# Python Script using Fileinput Module and with Regex substitution containing \n (multiple lines)

Tags: python, regex, readline

All,

I am relatively new to Python but have used other scripting languages with REGEX extensively.  I need a script that will open a file, look for a REGEX pattern, replace the pattern and close the file.  I have found that the below script works great, however, I dont know if the "for line in fileinput.input" command can accomodate for a regex pattern that exceeds a single line (i.e. the regex includes a carriage return).  In my instance, it covers 2 lines.  My test file read_it.txt looks like this

read_it.txt (contains just 3 lines)
ABA
CDC
EFE

The script is designed to open the file, recognize the pattern ABA\nCDC that is seen over 2 lines, then replace it with the word TEST.

If the pattern replace is successful, then the file should read as follows and contain now only 2 lines: 
TEST
EFE

Knowing the answer to this will help greatly in using Python scripts to parse text files and modify them on the fly.  I believe, but am not sure, that there may be a better Python construct that still allows for REGEX searches.  So the question is:

1) Do I need to change something in the existing script that would change the behavior of the "for line" command to match a multi-line REGEX pattern?
2) Or do I need a different Python script that is better suited to a multi-line search?

Some things that may help but I currently dont know how to write them are:

1) fileinput "readline" option.
2) adding (?m) in the expression for multline

Please help!

Brent

### SCRIPT

```
import sys
import fileinput
import re
for line in fileinput.input('C:\\Python34\\read_it.txt', inplace=1):
    line = re.sub(r'A(B)A$\nCDC', r'TEST', line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

Comment: note that the above formating makes it look like ABA CDC EFE are all on the same line in my file.  They are not: ABA is on the first line, CDC is on the second and EFE is on the third.  The result of the expression substitution I am trying above should return TEST on the first line and EFE on the second line with nothing on the third.

Comment: Do you want your program to recognize a pattern, or a simple fixed string?

Comment: what are you trying to replace?

Comment: I guess I am trying to replace a pattern.  A more simple pattern for our example would be the 3 letters ABA with a newline character.  It would be written in the REGEX as this ABA\n.  I would like to then replace that with a string (say TEST).  The result would be that my file would change in that I would have one less line in the file and the text ABA would be replaced by TEST.  Hope that makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) adding (?m) in the expression for multline

You can do this by adding `re.M` or `flags=re.MULTILINE` as an argument in `re.sub`

Example:-

```
re.sub(r'A(B)A$\nCDC', r'TEST', line.rstrip(), re.M)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'A(B)A$\nCDC', r'TEST', line.rstrip(), flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay.  I tried both methods but neither worked.  Here is the last attempt.  In it, I was just trying to match on ABA\n but it did not work.  I truly believe that the "for line in file" method of reading the file is the issue but I know of no other way to read a file using Python.  any thoughts?

Comment: import sys
import fileinput
import re
for line in fileinput.input('C:\\Python34\\read_it.txt', inplace=1):
    line = re.sub(r'A(B)A\n', r'test', line.rstrip(), flags=re.MULTILINE)
    print(line)